# Convert COO to CSR format in c++

Tags: c, sparse-matrix, intel-mkl

I have a matrix in the `COO` format. More specifically, there are three matrices `row_index`, `column_index`, `value`. Can you help me to convert this matrix format in `CSR` [format](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/471374#MKL_APPA_SMSF_2) with an efficient, not computationally expensive way, using C language? Are there libraries for this purpose?

**Example:**

[image]

**COO format:**

```
       row_index col_index value
          1         1         1
          1         2        -1
          1         3        -3   
          2         1        -2
          2         2         5
          3         3         4
          3         4         6
          3         5         4
          4         1        -4
          4         3         2
          4         4         7     
          5         2         8
          5         5        -5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Intel MKL documentation](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/mkl/mklman/GUID-92F3F5E4-ACFE-4CB7-9F1D-BBF3C2C74B2F.htm) (for `mkl_csrcoo`) states:

> Converts a sparse matrix in the CSR format to the coordinate format
>   and ***vice versa***.

And according to the above link you should set `job`:

`if job(1)=1, the matrix in the coordinate format is converted to the CSR format.`

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread, but, **assuming the COO data is (i,j) ordered/sorted**, as you show, a sequential algorithm to convert from COO to CSR is:

```
int main()
{
    // Example from Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix)

    // Matrix:
    // 10 20  0  0  0  0
    //  0 30  0 40  0  0
    //  0  0 50 60 70  0
    //  0  0  0  0  0 80

    // Expected output:
    // csr_val: 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80
    // csr_col:  0  1  1  3  2  3  4  5
    // csr_row:  0  2  4  7  8

    const int  nnz = 8; // number of non-zero elements
    const int rows = 4; // number of matrix rows
    const int cols = 6; // number of matrix columns

    // coo data:
    double coo_val[nnz] = { 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 60.0, 70.0, 80.0 };
    int    coo_row[nnz] = { 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3 };
    int    coo_col[nnz] = { 0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    // coo to csr:
    double csr_val[nnz]      = { 0 };
    int    csr_col[nnz]      = { 0 };
    int    csr_row[rows + 1] = { 0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < nnz; i++)
    {
        csr_val[i] = coo_val[i];
        csr_col[i] = coo_col[i];
        csr_row[coo_row[i] + 1]++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        csr_row[i + 1] += csr_row[i];
    }
}
```

Notice that, **assuming the COO data is (i,j) ordered/sorted**, `csr_col = coo_col` and `csr_val = coo_val`, so you just need to obtain `csr_row`, and that is as simples as:

```
int csr_row[rows + 1] = { 0 };
for (int i = 0; i < nnz; i++)
    csr_row[coo_row[i] + 1]++;
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    csr_row[i + 1] += csr_row[i];
```

So, in conclusion, you can easily achieve what you want with the 5 lines of code presented above.

**Final note:**

The proposed method has no considerations for duplicated COO entries.

Answer (score 1):

An implementation of this conversion is included in [`scipy`](http://scipy.org) (open source: BSD-licensed), the [function `coo_tocsr`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/3b36a57/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/coo.h#L34) in particular. It is in C++, but this is only in order to template the data and index types, and in order to initialise a data structure, so it can easily be transformed into C code.