# Convert COO to CSR format in python without scipy

Tags: python

I have similar question to:
[Convert COO to CSR format in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23583975/convert-coo-to-csr-format-in-c)
but in python.

I don't want to use SciPy.

COO format:

```
row_index col_index value
      1         1         1
      1         2        -1
      1         3        -3   
      2         1        -2
      2         2         5
      3         3         4
      3         4         6
      3         5         4
      4         1        -4
      4         3         2
      4         4         7     
      5         2         8
      5         5        -5
```

Desired output:

```
row_index col_index value
      0         1         1
      2         2        -1
      4         3        -3   
      7         1        -2
      8         2         5
                3         4
                4         6
                5         4
                1        -4
                3         2
                4         7     
                2         8
                5        -5
```

Comment: What are you asking for from us?  You already have the logic you need in the `c++` question.  If with that, you can't code up a similar solution in Python, then what is it that you want from the community?  You must want someone to write the equivalent code for you in Python.  That's off-topic on SO.  You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a specific question about your implementation. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation, and is not a way to have research, design or coding work done for you.

Comment: @CryptoFool I don't know C++ so I don't know how their answer logic works

Comment: Well, then get started with the approach anyway.  Get as close as you can, and then come back here for some help.  That's more what this place is about...helping with specific coding problems once an initial attempt has been made that can be shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to execute it in python:

```
nnz= len(value)
rows= max (row_index)+1
csr_row=[0]*(rows+1)

for i in range(nnz):
    csr_row[coo_row[i]+1]=csr_row[coo_row[i]+1]+1
for i in range(rows):
    csr_row[i+1]=csr_row[i+1]+csr_row[i]
    print("after: " , csr_row) # this helps the user follow along
```

Output:

```
after: [0, 2, 1, 3]
after: [0, 2, 3, 3]
after: [0, 2, 3, 6]
```